# TYPO3 SolrConnection removed search, what now?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

what is the new approach to fetch data from solr within an extbase Service class?  we previously did it with

```
 $solrResponse = $this->solr->search('type:car', $offset, $limit);
```

$this->solr is an instance of

```
ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\System\Solr\SolrConnection
```

but the method **search** got removed in the newer version of the extension "apache-solr-for-typo3/solr" (currently using 9.0.2) and now i cant find the replacement for that one.

did someone else got that issue too? why we need that in an extension service? well we index an external graphQL into our TYPO3-solr.

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have switched to Solarium as a new PHP Solr Library.

https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

or dig here:

https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/tree/master/Classes/Search

HTH

Olivier

Comment: thanks, we just actually switch to the new introduced SolrWriteService and SolrReadService, the Reader has the already known search method, i will post if it all works out or no ;)

Comment: nope, solarium is the right way because the extension uses those classes already internally.